# How to streaming all files in directory in "input" (FFmpeg HLS stream)

Tags: ffmpeg, hls, live-streaming

There is this command that sends files (input1.mp4, input2.mp4...) as an HLS stream to the site,

> ffmpeg -i -re input1.mp4 -f hls -hls_time 4 -hls_playlist_type event /opt/metal-country_ru/live/stream.m3u8

but only plays one file. I want to make sure that all the files that are in the directory are consistently and continuously sent in one stream to the site's player. I'm not good at this topic, so please help.